# Python anagram strings

Tags: python

I'm supposed to write a function to determine if two strings are anagrams or not.

The codes I've written now, doesn't really work well.

For example, one of sample input is

```
Tom Cruise
So I'm cuter
```

output should be `True`, but my code keep says `False`.

For another example, when the input is

```
the eyes
they see
```

My code actually says `True` which is the right answer.

So I have no idea why my code only works for certain input.

Can anyone help?

```
def anagram(a, b):

    if(sorted(a)==sorted(b)):
        return True
    else:
        return False
```

Comment: I did, but its the same. :(

Comment: You need to remove symbols such as `'`, and keep only letter characters.

Comment: You mean the symbols from input? I'm not suppose to remove that. This is why it gives me headache

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I mentioned in the comment section above, you need to remove any symbol such as `'` and convert each letter to either uppercase or lowercase to avoid case mismatches. So, your code should look like this:

```
def anagram(a, b):

    newA = ''.join(elem.lower() for elem in a if elem.isalpha())
    newB = ''.join(elem.lower() for elem in b if elem.isalpha())

    if(sorted(newA)==sorted(newB)):
        return True
    else:
        return False

a = "Tom Cruise"
b = "So I'm cuter"

print(anagram(a,b))
```

This will give you:

```
True
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to remove all the non alphabet characters and then convert all letters to lower case:

```
import re
regex = re.compile('[^a-zA-Z]')
return sorted(regex.sub('', a).lower()) == sorted(regex.sub('', b).lower())
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def anagram(a, b):
    a = ''.join(e for e in a if e.isalpha()).lower()
    b = ''.join(e for e in b if e.isalpha()).lower()
    return sorted(a)==sorted(b)

a = "Tom Cruise"
b = "So I'm cuter"
anagram(a,b)
```

You got to remove the none alpha characters in the string and convert the two string into the consistent case.

Answer (score 0):

```
Check this one...

s1=input("Enter first string:")
s2=input("Enter second string:")
a=''.join(t for t in s1 if t.isalnum())
b=''.join(t for t in s2 if t.isalnum())
a=a.lower()
b=b.lower()
if(sorted(a)==sorted(b)):
      print("The strings are anagrams.")
else:
      print("The strings aren't anagrams.")
```